# ASP.NET MVC with jQuery - How to consider all decimals after the comma, It's only showing two digits

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem, that when entering a number that for example has this format: 12,345 the last digit is not being saved.

When I check the database, the saved number was: 12,34
How would I make the system consider all decimal digits after the comma?

```
public class InvetoryViewModel
{
    public InvetoryViewModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal AguaCarregada { get; set; } 
    public decimal DieselCarregado { get; set; }
```

}

Page

```
         <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">                        
                    <label for="embarcacaoInput">Água</label>
                    <input type="text" step="000.000" class="form-control" id="estoque-barco-agua">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="embarcacaoInput">Diesel</label>
                    <input type="number"  step="000.000" class="form-control" id="estoque-barco-diesel">
                </div>
            </div>
```

jQuery

```
function saveInvetory() {
    $("#message-estoque").removeClass("alert-danger");
    $("#message-estoque").removeClass("alert-warning");
    var barcoId = $("#estoque-barco-id").val();
    var agua = $("#estoque-barco-agua").val().replace(",", ".");
    var diesel = $("#estoque-barco-diesel").val().replace(",", ".");
    var data = JSON.stringify({ AguaCarregada: parseFloat(agua), DieselCarregado: parseFloat(diesel), BarcoId: barcoId });
    if (agua == "" || diesel == "") {
        $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-warning");
        $("#message-estoque").html("Preencha todos os campos para continuar");
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/InfoApontamento/AtualizarEstoqueBarco",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {

        if (!result.Success) {

            $("#message-estoque").html(result.ErrorDatail);
            $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-danger");
        }
        else if (!result.Data) {
            $("#message-estoque").html(result.Message);
            $("#message-estoque").addClass("alert-danger");
        }
        else {
            alert("Salvo com sucesso!");
            $("#modal-estoque").modal('hide');
            $('#estoque-barco-agua').val("");
            $('#estoque-barco-diesel').val("");
            // abrirModalManutencao();
            preInicializarModal();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: *When I check the database* - looks like your database is defined to store as 2 decimal places.  Maybe check the Action to see what's being received from the POST.  Neither of which you've included.

Comment: Did you check how is the data is arriving at your Controller? Maybe you need to redefine your column in your table by specifying decimal(12,3) instead of just decimal.

Comment: @Andres2142 thx, i checked the database and you're right, it's flagged as Decimal (18,2), I changed it to (14,3). But now, if I type, for example, 100.123, the system is replacing the last number '3', for '0', would you have an idea of what the reason is?

Comment: Your "agua" and "diesel" variables in your js script, how do they look like? try console.log( ) those variables, if you see them wrong, maybe is because you are using the "step" property in your input field,  remove that and see if it works.